# Can the Raspberry Pi's Bluetooth be put into "promiscuous" mode?

Tags: bluetooth, raspberry-pi, bluetooth-lowenergy, meta-raspberrypi

Can the Bluetooth adapter included in the Raspberry Pi models be put into some sort of "promiscuous" mode -- so that it reports to the host *all* Bluetooth-activity that it "hears", even if it is not itself part of the conversation?

I'm not trying to break encryption, just want to be aware of any BT-radio activity going on in the device's proximity...

Answer (score 0):

Since there is documentation how to capture Bluetooth traffic with wireshark (or tshark) it might be possible.

Check out [this article](https://wiki.wireshark.org/CaptureSetup/Bluetooth)

Comment: For pcap-based methods to work, the communicating devices must have paired already. The article says, for _passive_ capture one has to use [Ubertooth](http://greatscottgadgets.com/ubertoothone/). So, I'm afraid, the answer to my question is "No"...